# Android ndk example native-audio error

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, opensl

I try to use the example code for OpenSl ES wich is included in NDK in Android Studio.
It didn't work as you will see later on. So I need help to use the code in Android Studio.
 The Code was written for Eclipse but I used the import function from Android Studio to include it. I tried it Eclipse also and it worked fine but when trying to run the code in Android Studio I get the following Errorcode

```
/home/flex/AndroidStudioProjects/native-audio1/app/src/main/jni/native-audio-jni.c
Error:(155) undefined reference to `slCreateEngine'
Error:(165) undefined reference to `SL_IID_ENGINE'
Error:(165) undefined reference to `SL_IID_ENGINE'
Error:(170) undefined reference to `SL_IID_ENVIRONMENTALREVERB'
Error:(170) undefined reference to `SL_IID_ENVIRONMENTALREVERB'
Error:(215) undefined reference to `SL_IID_BUFFERQUEUE'
Error:(215) undefined reference to `SL_IID_EFFECTSEND'
Error:(215) undefined reference to `SL_IID_VOLUME'
Error:(215) undefined reference to `SL_IID_BUFFERQUEUE'

...

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/home/flex/AndroidStudioProjects/native-audio1/app/build/intermediates/ndk/debug/obj/local/arm64-v8a/libnative-audio-jni.so] Error 1
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/flex/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.942 secs
Information:38 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

What I have done so far:
I changed 
build.gradle (app) to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nativeaudio"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19

        ndk {
            moduleName "native-audio-jni" //I included this one
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

}
```

Further on I changed local.properties to

```
sdk.dir=/home/flex/Android/Sdk
ndk.dir=/home/flex/android-ndk-r10e
```

My Android.mk looks like this

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := native-audio-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native-audio-jni.c
# for native audio
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lOpenSLES
# for logging
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog
# for native asset manager
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -landroid

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

my apllication.mk:

```
APP_ABI := all
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was to compile the source code twice.

So in the terminal I compiled the first time with the command : `ndk-build`
And the second time I used the command: `ndk-build TARGET_PLATFORM=android-xy`
`xy` must be replaced with android version

This is definitly not the correct way but at least it made it work.

Comment: could you please elaborate your answer. I could understand nothing from it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may just need to add

```
ldLibs.addAll(["OpenSLES"])
```

Insde the `ndk{ }` field in the `build.gradle` file. That's what solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I've never tried OpenSL ES on Android, but maybe you could try to change the LOCAL_LDLIBS to (according to [this](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/ndk/docs/opensles/) site) :

- LOCAL_LDLIBS := libOpenSLES

Maybe try also to build for each platform a step at a time (not 'all' in APP_ABI)